# Get key_tags from the dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have following dictionary, I want all the keys(ie which tag it belong to, for example, adrenaline or air etc.) for each city.

```
dictionary = {u'adrenaline': {u'estimated_total': 234,
u'more': True,
u'results': [{u'adrenaline_score': 2.11474252688113, u'name': u'Rome'},
             {u'adrenaline_score': 1.94859310493828, u'name': u'Budapest'},
             {u'adrenaline_score': 2.65914794847249, u'name': u'Ubud'},
             {u'adrenaline_score': 1.94859310493828, u'name': u'Calgary'},
             {u'adrenaline_score': 3.0, u'name': u'Canc\xfan'}]},
u'air': {u'estimated_total': 234,
u'more': True,
u'results': [{u'air_score': 1.50402325242855, u'name': u'Paris'},
           {u'air_score': 1.50402325242855, u'name': u'Rome'},
           {u'air_score': 1.50402325242855, u'name': u'New York City'},
           {u'air_score': 1.50402325242855, u'name': u'Abu Dhabi'},
           {u'air_score': 1.50402325242855, u'name': u'Key West'},
           {u'air_score': 1.50402325242855, u'name': u'Salt Lake City'}]}
```

relevant tags(keys)  and scores with respect to the city.

Output:

```
     {'Rome': {'adrenaline': 2.11474252688113, 'air': 1.50402325242855},
      'Budapest': {'adrenaline': 1.94859310493828},
      'Ubud': {'adrenaline': 2.65914794847249},
      'Calgary': {'adrenaline': 1.94859310493828}....}
```

Comment: So you want a new dictionary where the keys are the cities and the values are the air score or adrenaline score?

Comment: What's the expected output? A dict like `{'Rome': 'adrenaline', 'Budapest': 'adrenaline', 'Paris': 'air', ...}`?

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't name dictionaries `dict` as that overrides a builtin name.

Comment: The output you want is unclear, please edit your answer to include the desired output.

Comment: point noted @chrisz

Comment: yes, with there score also any suggestions @aran-fey

Comment: I see you edited the question but the output you want is still very unclear... instead of saying "with their score", please show an actual output with the score too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming your dict `d` to not use the reserved keyword `dict`, you can do something like this (adapt per the output you want, which is unclear):

```
In [1]:
result = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    for score_row in v['results']:
        city = score_row['name']
        if not city in result.keys():
            result[city] = {}
        result[city][k] = score_row['{}_score'.format(k)]

Out[1]:
{'Rome': {'adrenaline': 2.11474252688113, 'air': 1.50402325242855},
 'Budapest': {'adrenaline': 1.94859310493828},
 'Ubud': {'adrenaline': 2.65914794847249},
 'Calgary': {'adrenaline': 1.94859310493828},
 'Cancún': {'adrenaline': 3.0},
 'Paris': {'air': 1.50402325242855},
 'New York City': {'air': 1.50402325242855},
 'Abu Dhabi': {'air': 1.50402325242855},
 'Key West': {'air': 1.50402325242855},
 'Salt Lake City': {'air': 1.50402325242855}}
```